# ページの一部分処理を維持して、他のページに移動しても変わらない方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

サイトのheader部分に全サイトのfont-sizeが選択できるメニューを作ります。
[S][M][L]で分けて、それぞれ押すとサイトのfont-sizeが変わります。
そして、他のページに移動してもfont-sizeは選択したまま維持する。

一応jQueryで単ページのcss変更はできましたが、他のページにクリックしたらfont-sizeリセットされます、何かいい方法はありましょうか？

Answer (score 1):

文字サイズ変更のボタンがクリックされたらsessionStorageに各文字サイズに応じた名前を持たせてみたらどうでしょうか
画面読み込み時にsessionStorageに名前を持っていたら文字サイズを変更するようにするといった処理をすれば同じドメイン内なら出来ると思います

[[Cookie・WebStorage]ブラウザにデータを保存する](http://qiita.com/shuntaro_tamura/items/004a2c8fb42f107d88e3)